# Very confusing error with no cause mentioned

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synthesis

Could someone please tell me why I'm getting this error? I'm still very new to Verilog, so please pardon any obvious flaws. Thanks!

```
module func(clk,d,out);
input [3:0] d;
input clk;

reg [3:0] q[1:0];
output  [3:0] out;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
q[0][3:0]=d[3:0];
q[1][3:0]=d[3:0];

end
assign out=q[0]^q[1];

endmodule
```

> :ERROR:Xst:917 - Undeclared signal <>.
>   FATAL_ERROR:Xst:Portability/export/Port_Main.h:127:1.13 - This application has discovered an exceptional condition from which it cannot recover. Process will terminate.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Which version of ISE are you using? I've tried your code in ISE 14.2 and it works fine. looks to me as if you have found a bug in your ISE version. (btw: you should use nonblocking assignments (<=) instead of blocking assignments (=) in this always block in order to avoid synthesis-simulation mismatches)

Answer (score 1):

Try switch the order of the lines `reg [3:0] q[1:0];` and `output [3:0] out;`.

Your code compiles on my simulator, so I'm guessing this is a bug in your simulator. However general recommendation is to always declare `input`/`output`/`inout` before all internal values.

I would recommend you change your port syntax to IEEE Std 1364-2001 style. Ex:

```
module func(
    input        clk,
    input  [3:0] d,
    output [3:0] out );
```

As other have suggested, you should switch the blocking-assignments (`=`) to non-blocking-assignments (`<=`) within your `always` block. This fix will is not the compiling issue, but it will get you into a better coding style and save you from simple syntheses not matching RTL headaches in the future.

Answer (score 0):

More questions than answers:

What tool are you using?  Does the tool support synthesizing a register array?

You should use non-blocking assignments for sequential logic:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    q[0][3:0] <= d[3:0];
    q[1][3:0] <= d[3:0];
end
```

Memories are conventionally declared with 0 to the left of the colon and the last location to the right:

```
reg [3:0] q [0:1];
```